# Emacs haskell intero mode, import could not find module

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

Edit: this error occurs only when using emacs haskell mode and intero mode (`C-c C-l` to load into ghci). It works in command line using `stack ghc Log.hs LogAnalysis.hs`.

I'm learning Haskell through CIS 194 (Spring 2013), and am running into this problem when doing [homework 2](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/02-ADTs.pdf). The homework folder is very simple:

```
homework2
|-- LogAnalysis.hs
|-- Log.hs
|-- error.log
|-- sample.log
```

Some data types are defined in `Log.hs`, and need to be imported into `LogAnalysis.hs`, which is the file I need to work on. The first few lines in `LogAnalysis.hs` are like this:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module LogAnalysis where

import Log

-- Exercise 1: parse an individual message
...
```

However, I got error message like this in my emacs using haskell mode with intero:

```
error:
    Could not find module 'Log'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

(Hit 'C-c C-r' in the Haskell buffer to apply suggestions.)
```

Same message appears when using 'C-c C-l' to load to ghci within emacs.

But this error doesn't appear when loading `LogAnalysis.hs` in command line using `stack ghci`, the message is instead:

```
Prelude> :l LogAnalysis.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Log              ( Log.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling LogAnalysis      ( LogAnalysis.hs, interpreted )
Ok, two modules loaded.
*LogAnalysis>
```

So I'm guessing this error has something to do with my emacs' setup of haskell mode and intero mode, but couldn't find any available solution yet.

Thanks for reading this question, your help will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you compile this? You need to add the `Log.hs` file when compiling, so `ghc Log.hs LogAnalysis.hs`.

Comment: [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) I'm able to compile using `stack ghc Log.hs LogAnalysis.hs` in command line, this error only occurs in my current workflow using emacs haskell mode and intero mode, when using `C-c C-l`. Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `intero` needs a `package.yaml` and a `stack.yaml` in order to locate your source files. You can just run `stack init` or `stack new` to auto matically generate these project files.
I met this problem several times. The above method solved my problem on my Windows and Fedora, so I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks and accepted as answer. I also wrote down the process of solving it as my own answer to expand yours a little. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Krantz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50551836/4794274) and some more reading, the problem is solved by creating a new project with stack so intero knows the location of my source files.
Thus this problem is caused by intero's not knowing where to look for local modules when in `intero-global-mode` in emacs. 
Here I'll write my own answer here to expand [Krantz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8578679/krantz)'s answer a little more, and to document the process of solving this problem as a beginner to Haskell:

For intero to be able to import local modules, we should avoid using `intero-global-mode` and instead creating a local project (which in hindsight makes more sense to me).

So in the case of this Homework 2, instead of moving files to a homework folder as described in the question, I'll `stack new homework2`, and move the sources files into `homework2\src`. Then when using emacs to load `LogAnalysis.hs`, instead of this previous message I got in **`*intero:global-project::repl*`**:

```
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/[username]/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/intero/intero-[script]
```

and error message when loading `LogAnalysis.hs`, I'm now able to get:

```
Loaded GHCi configuration from /path/to/homework2/.stack-work/intero/intero-[script]
```

in **`*intero:homework2:homework2:repl*`**. And using `C-c C-l` to load `LogAnalysis.hs` now gets:

```
[2 of 2] Compiling LogAnalysis      ( /path/to/homework2/src/LogAnalysis.hs, interpreted ) [flags changed]
Ok, two modules loaded.
```

So problem solved.